# Why am I able to modify this const char* array?

Tags: c, string, constants

Why does this work? It seems to me assigning `a[0] = "X"` should fail because `const` should make the data in the array immutable. However it compiles and runs fine, with and without `const`.

```c
const char* a[] = {"a", "b", "c"};
a[0] = "X";
printf("%s\n", a[0]);
```

Comment: What `a[i]` *points to* is immutable, but `a[i]` is not.  `a[i]` is a *pointer to `const char`*.  The pointer can be changed to point to a different `const char` object.

Comment: it is : `declare a as array of pointer to const char` . So this one will not compile a[0][0] = 'x';

Comment: wrong dupe - it is something different